Is there well-known definition of equivalent/non-equivalent sequences of sets?
Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an unbounded, Borel set. Suppose, $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(\cdot)$ be the Hausdorff dimension and $\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(\cdot)}(\cdot)$ is the Hausdorff measure in its dimension on the Borel sigma-algebra.
The sequences below are sequences of sets with a set theoretic limit of $A$:
$${\large \overrightarrow{F_1}= (F_{r_1}^{(1)})_{r_1\in\mathbb{N}}, \overrightarrow{F_2}=(F_{r_2}^{(2)})_{{r_2\in\mathbb{N}}},\cdot\cdot\cdot,\overrightarrow{F_s}=(F_{r_s}^{(s)})_{{r_s\in\mathbb{N}}}}$$
Hence, suppose $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is an arbitrary set. Again, the sequences of bounded sets in $\left\{\overrightarrow{F_s}:s\in S\right\}$ have set theoretic limits of $A$.
Question: Is there a well-known definition of equivalent/non-equivalent sequences of bounded sets?

(Definition 1) Equivalent Sequences of Sets
Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be an arbitrary set. The sequences of bounded sets in:
$$\left\{\overrightarrow{F_s}:s\in S\right\}$$ are
equivalent, when for all $k,v\in S $, where $k\neq v$, $\overrightarrow{F_k}$ and $\overrightarrow{F_v}$ are equivelant: i.e., there exists a $N^{\prime}\in \mathbb{N}$, such that for all $r_k\ge N^{\prime}$, there
exists a $r_v\in \mathbb{N}$, where:
$$\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(F_{r_k}^{(k)})}(F_{r_k}^{(k)}
 \Delta\:\! F_{r_v}^{(v)})=0$$ and for all $r_v\ge N^{\prime}$, there
exists a $r_k\in \mathbb{N}$, where:
$$\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(F_{r_v}^{(v)})}(F_{r_k}^{(k)} \Delta
 \: \! F_{r_v}^{(v)})=0$$


(Definition 2) Non-Equivalent Sequences of Sets
Suppose $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is an arbitrary set. All
sequences of bounded sets in:
$$\left\{\overrightarrow{F_s}:s\in S\right\}$$ are
non-equivalent, if def. 1 is false, meaning for some $k,v\in S $, where $k\neq v$, $\overrightarrow{F_k}$ and $\overrightarrow{F_v}$ are non-equivelant: i.e., there exists an $N^{\prime}\in\mathbb{N}$, such for all $r_k\ge N^{\prime}$, there exists a $r_v\in\mathbb{N}$, where:
$$\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(F_{r_k}^{(k)})}(F_{r_k}^{(k)}
 \Delta\:\! F_{r_v}^{(v)})\neq 0$$ or for all $r_v\ge N^{\prime}$, there exist a $r_k\in \mathbb{N}$, where:
$$\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(F_{r_v}^{(v)})}(F_{r_k}^{(k)}
\Delta \: \! F_{r_v}^{(v)})\neq 0$$

Edit: Fixed the notations
Edit 2: Fixed the definitions

What is $F_{r_s}$? What is the context where these sets appear? Is $F'{r_s}$ the set of accumulation points of $F{r_s}$?

@newaccount $F_{r_s}$ is the $s$-th sequence of a sequence of sets whose set theoretic limit is $A$. The "$\prime$" doesn't refer to the set of accumalation points. Inorder, to enumerate the sets differently without using so many letters and variables, I decided to use the "$\prime$" variable. Is there a better way of defining this?

Why not follow the notation in the wiki article and just let $(A_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ be a sequence whose limit is $A$?

@newaccount Then, how will I be able to define "equivelant" and "non-equivelant" sequences of bounded sets? In general, I'm defining "equivelant" and "non-equivelant" sequences of sets in a set of those seqeunces.

Well I don't know because it's hard to understand your definitions. You said $F_{r_s}$ is "the $s$-th sequence of a sequence of sets", but that doesn't make sense. Do we have one sequence for each $s\in S$? So basically we have a matrix of sets? Then $F_{r_s}$ is not the right notation for the $s$-th sequence. Use something like $\overrightarrow{F_s}=(F^{(s)}_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$.

As far as I see, you do not need to define the equivalence for the sequence
$\left{\overrightarrow{F_s}:s\in S\right}$. It suffices to define equivalence of $\overrightarrow{F_s}$ and $\overrightarrow{F_t}$ for any distinct $s,t\in S$ as you did and then to require that for any distinct $s,t\in S$, the sequences $\overrightarrow{F_s}$ and $\overrightarrow{F_t}$ are equivalent.

Unfortunately, I never heard about such equivalence. But it is too special and I am not a specialist.
Maybe the closest thing which it reminds me is the following. Given a metric space $(X,d)$, let $(\exp X, H_d)$ be the extended metric space of closed subsets of $X$ endowed with the Hausdorff distance, and then define an equivalence of Cauchy sequences of elements of $\exp X$ as usual.

@AlexRavsky I clarified the definitions.
